# Is it possible to use javascript to have a 'chance' to redirect to a different page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'll try explain it further, I'm building a web-art website and there is a page that is supposed to have rare chance to redirect to a different page.

After 10 seconds, the page redirects to two possible pages, one being rarer than the other basically

Just one page that has a chance to redirect to two different possible pages.

I have the code down for it to redirect to the common page after 10 secs:

```
<script> var timer = setTimeout(function() { window.location='/error.html' }, 10000); </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Something like this: `var rareChance = 0.01; if (Math.random()<rareChance) window.location='rare.html'; else window.location='common.html';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will wait 10 seconds and redirect to a random page, `rare.html` or `normal.html`. The `rare.html` page will get hit 15% of the time, `normal.html` will get hit 85% of the time.

```html
<script>
var WAIT_MS = 10000; // 10 seconds
var PERCENT = 0.15;  // 15% chance
setTimeout(function() {
    if (Math.random() <= PERCENT) {
        window.location = 'rare.html'
    } else {
        window.location = 'normal.html'
    }
}, WAIT_MS);
</script>
```

We can prove this works by running the `Math.random()` function 100 times and we should see *about* 15 results less than `0.15`.

```js
var PERCENT = 0.15;
var rareCount = 0;
var normalCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (Math.random() <= PERCENT) {
        rareCount++;
    } else {
        normalCount++;
    }
}
console.log(rareCount, ' rare');
console.log(normalCount, ' normal');
```